# Default generic parameter that depends on an optional trait bound

Tags: generics, rust

I have an enum that can store either an owned or borrowed, like below. It is similar to [`std::borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) but doesn't actually provide clone-on-write functionality.

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

enum RefOrOwned<'a, B, T>
where
    B: ?Sized,
    T: Borrow<B>,
{
    Ref(&'a B),
    Owned(T),
}
```

It can be used like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let str = RefOrOwned::<str, String>::Ref("Hi :D");
}
```

I would like the compiler to infer the `T` type for me. I thought of using the [`std::borrow::ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html) trait: if `B: ToOwned<Owned = T>`, then `T` should be set to `B::Owned` by default. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the type as having a default of `<B as ToOwned>::Owned`, and `B` won't be required to implement `ToOwned` unless the default is actually used:

```rust
enum RefOrOwned<'a, B, T = <B as ToOwned>::Owned>
where
    B: ?Sized,
    T: Borrow<B>,
{
    Ref(&'a B),
    Owned(T),
}
```

However, this will only work when you specify the types explicitly, i.e. `RefOrOwned::<str>`. If you leave them inferred (`RefToOwned::Ref("Hi :D")`), the default won't be used. I don't think there is a way to force a default in such situation.

Comment: Do you know why the default won't be used when leaving the `B` and `T` inferred? It seems a bit odd to me...

Comment: @Debaug What do you mean by "why"? Those are the rules of the language, defaults are only used when type parameters are specified explicitly.

Comment: I was asking why the language was designed that way. It seems to me that making the compiler infer defaults when using type inference anyway is a perfectly natural choice. Unless there's something I'm not seeing, of course.

Comment: @Debaug "Defaults affecting type inference" is a big and important feature that many people want. Problem is, it is also very difficult to implement. I don't understant alot why, but I know that in the current compiler implementation it is very hard to do and may even require waiting for a rework of the inference engine.

Comment: @Debaug Unless you meant that the compiler will _always_ use the defaulted type, in which case the answer is that inference is more important and more commonly wanted.